# Hadoop installation on Ubuntu Server using VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, virtualbox

I was trying to install Hadoop on the Ubuntu Server using Virtual Box.
I used the download link from the apache's website .
i used the command `wget http://mirror.fibergrid.in/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz`
but itsays

> wget:unable to resolve host address

What should I do?

Comment: The link seems to work, so you should check you have access to the internet from your VM, the `wget` failed to do a DNS lookup.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the link and was able to download file. Besides checking for the access to internet, try other mirror sites from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common

Thanks.

Comment: yes, I had problem with my internet connection thanks.